# Beginner PHP XPath Text Display

Tags: php, xpath

Goal: Use xpath checker/Firefox and PHP to display selective text on a webpage.

What would be the PHP XPATH code required in order to display just the name (text) on this page? http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197967713768

Using this code:

```
<?php
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197967713768');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//div[@class='persona_name']" );
foreach ($nodelist as $n){
echo $n->nodeValue."\n";
}
?>
```

I get the output of "*mopar410 This user has also played as:*" **I would like to only have it display "mopar410"**. I would like to remove the *"This user has also played as:"* portion.

Some information cannot be accessed via xml though, and when I replace the above with this from xpath checker in Firefox (example):

```
<?php
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197967713768');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "/x:html/x:body/x:div[3]/x:div[1]/x:div/x:div/x:div/x:div[3]/x:div[1]']" );
foreach ($nodelist as $n){
echo $n->nodeValue."\n";
}
?>
```

It doesn't work and I get an error. What is the proper method of right-clicking and viewing the XPATH, then transferring that xpath to the PHP code?

```
Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Undefined namespace prefix in blahblahblah on line 85

Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in blahblahblah on line 85

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in blahblahblah on line 86
```

I am new to this. Please help.

Comment: The `/x:` is a namespace, e.g., `<x:html>`. You might have seen this in Word Docs exported as XML: `<o:html>`. Typically you need to [register namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php) so the namespace can be recognized.

Comment: Hi Jared, I am not sure what namespace to register or the exact way to do it. I used this (found online) "$xpath->registerNamespace("x", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");" but it gives back an error of arning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in blahblahblah on line 86

Comment: That's because invalid expression is a different error caused by the XPath query (the `/x:html/x:/body...` part) being malformed. The `']` at the end of the path looks suspect to me. But something is wrong on that line where it's not a correct syntax.

Comment: Ah yes. I cleaned up the code and removed that - now nothing is displayed on the screen (no errors and no text). Progress... sort of?

Comment: Maybe your query isn't correct.

Comment: I changed the query to "/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]" removing the x: portions and it does display now. However, it displays "mopar410 This user has also played as:" .... and I only want the "mopar410" portion.

Comment: You're almost there. Good luck. `:)`

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction? I guess it is a similar problem to my other issue.. whereas the text returned is "  (Not Specified) 22.3% (0%*)" and I only want to keep the "22.3" portion.

Comment: It's entirely based on the related XML. You can try asking another question. Try viewing the source, I bet there's markup you're not seeing.

Comment: You are likely right.. trying my best here. This is the page in question: http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197967713768/ - When viewing just the source code from the URL.. I see there is other text inside the main div.. which includes that "this player has also played as: portion". hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `<div class="persona_name">` contains other nodes and texts besides the text you wanted. You can try using XPath expression for getting only non empty text node that is direct child of `<div class="persona_name">` :

```
//div[@class='persona_name']/text()[normalize-space(.)]
```

Comment: Hi har - thank you for your input. Could you explain a little about the xpath you used? I get it that we are selecting the div with a class of persona name, but what is the portion afterwards with text and normalizing space? "getting only non empty text node as a direct child" means it will acquire the very first "thing" under persona_name.. so long as it has text in it?

Comment: `/text()` will get direct child text nodes (those aren't nested within other tags). Then `[normalize-space(.)]` will filter those text nodes further to non empty ones (you may be able to drop this filter but in the XPath tool I'm using it is necessary)

Comment: Hi Har. In response to this...what would be the correct sequence to convert this to a string, so I could INSERT INTO a mysql table?  echo ($nodelist->$n);  ?

Comment: I'm not the right person to answer PHP related question